# Iteration over a nested set gives the out-of-index error

Tags: python-2.7, set, iteration

I am writing a tik-tak-toe game. In place of using a number of combinations such as

```
def check_win(self,mark):
    return ((self.bd[1]==self.bd[2]==self.bd[3]==mark) or
        (self.bd[4] ==self.bd[5] ==self.bd[6] ==mark) or
        (self.bd[7]==self.bd[8]==self.bd[9] ==mark) or
        (self.bd[1] ==self.bd[4] ==self.bd[7] ==mark) or
        (self.bd[2] ==self.bd[5] ==self.bd[8] ==mark) or
        (self.bd[3] ==self.bd[6] ==self.bd[9]==mark) or
        (self.bd[1] ==self.bd[5] ==self.bd[9]==mark) or
        (self.bd[3] ==self.bd[5] ==self.bd[7]==mark)
        )
```

Want to use smaller code, but it is giving me out in index error.

```
win_comb = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,6),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7))
def check_win(self,mark):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    for elem in self.win_comb:
        if self.win_comb[elem[0]]== self.win_comb[elem[1]]== self.win_comb[elem[2]]==mark:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

ERROR:

```
if self.win_comb[elem[0]]== self.win_comb[elem[1]]== self.win_comb[elem[2]]==mark:IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Your already looping through the individual tuples in `win_comb`, and then attempting to index `win_comb` with those elements (`win_comb[elem]`). Just use `elem[0]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the code as following, it is always tie even any Player wins

```
def check_win(self,mark):
#pdb.set_trace()
for elem in self.win_comb:
    if elem[0]]== elem[1]== elem[2]==mark:
        return True
else:
    return False    



e Player-1, Enter your position from 1 to 9 9
 X| O | X
```

---

```
 O| X | O
```

---

```
 X| O | X
```

This is a tie
play again(yes/no)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the new loop-based version of your function, you never inspect the board state at all!  In other words, where is the reference to `self.bd`?  It's missing!